# Configurei todas permissões para usar as APIs do Graph API do Instragram e estou tomando erro

Tags: instagram-api

Sou novo trabalhando com as APIs do facebook e instagram, configurei minha conta para acessar as APIs do Graph API do instagram:

- Criei aplicativo, coloquei o produto de Graph API do Instagram;
- Verifiquei a empresa para poder usar a permissão public_profile advanced;
- Coloquei todas essas permissões:
  *email, pages_show_list, ads_management, business_management, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights, instagram_content_publish, whatsapp_business_management, instagram_manage_messages, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_posts, whatsapp_business_messaging, instagram_branded_content_brand, instagram_branded_content_creator*

OBS: Algumas desnecessárias, porém fui colocando enquanto testava.

Quando tento chamar o endpoint, graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{instagram-id}?fields=id%2Cname, passando o ID da minha conta do instagram, recebo esse erro:

"message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"

O que pode ser?

Comment: Tentou trocar `?fields=id%2Cname` por `?fields=id,name` (Sem o escape na virgula)? No lugar de `{instagram-id}` colocou o ID da conta?